# Installing Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I decided to learn symfony so I tried to install it. After getting composer like said in the website, I executed the following command to create a project and get symfony2

> composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition Website/test

and unfortunately I got this as a message:

```
>    Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.7.1)
      - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.7.1)
        Downloading: 100%    

---


>    Created project in Website/test
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**


- Installation request for sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5].

- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

**Problem 2**

- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.0 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5].

- Installation request for sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.0 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v4.0.0].
```

*The composer.json file :*

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

and I got a PHP 5.5.9 version and ubuntu 14.04 as OS.

Can someone explain to me why I'm getting these errors and how to solve them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per your errors, the problem is you don't have the PHP cURL extension installed.

In Ubuntu, try the following to install the packages

`sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl`

Now try again.

Comment: Work like a charm, it was the php5-curl that was missing curl was already installed. Thank you sir!

Comment: No this is wrong. I have curl installed correctly. But still have the problem

Comment: Well, it's not wrong. If it doesn't work for you, then either a) you've missed the php5-curl bit (I notice your comment only mentioned that cURL was installed) or b) your environment is set up differently, in which case you should probably ask a new question specific to your setup.